# CellClick Event in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to Asp.net but I want to implement `CellClick` event for asp's GridView,
like in windows application `dataGridView1_CellClick()`.

Comment: Hi Mr_Green, thanks for edit and place this in proper manner

Comment: You need to ask a question.  What is your question - what are you having problems with and what have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

You could add some jQuery to your `.aspx` page. If you want to process something on the server, you can call from jQuery the `PageMethods.YourServerMethod` (ex. `SetName` for this code snippet). The `SetName` method definition follows below.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptMgr" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="content" runat="server">
            <asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#gridView td").click(function () {
            PageMethods.SetName("JavaScript!", onSuccessMethod, onFailMethod);
        });

        function onSuccessMethod(response) { alert(response); }
        function onFailMethod() { }
    </script>
</body>
```

In the code behind file:

```
using System.Web.Services;

...

[WebMethod]
public static String SetName(string name)
{
    return "This was called from " + name;
}
```